# Android : OutOfMemoryError Error while opening InfoWindow on Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, google-maps-markers

I am using native android code in my react-native app to display google maps and having 200+ markers on google maps with clustering and trying to open info window on each marker i tap on. It works fine for 3-4 minutes but after that,OutOfMemoryError Exception occurs which leads to crash the app. Is there any solution for the same?

Comment: Is this in the Android simulator or a physical device ?

Comment: @Blimeys Its on the physical device

Answer (score 0):

Use below the line in manifest inside application tag
android:largeHeap="true"

Also, make sure there is no memory leakage.